# Login in website Exception

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, web-scraping, web-crawler, webclient

Hi ever body I am new in c# webscraping.

I want to login to http://telelisting.ca/ but I cant. I have used `WebClient`, `WebBrowser` and now `HttpWebRequest`, but the same errors occured all the time which is server exception 500.

Can any body help me what i am doing wrong??

```
CookieCollection cookies = new CookieCollection();
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://telelisting.ca/");
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
request.CookieContainer.Add(cookies);
//Get the response from the server and save the cookies from the first request..
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
cookies = response.Cookies;
string getUrl = "http://telelisting.ca/";
string postData = String.Format("ctl00_LoginPopup1_Login1_UserName={0}&ctl00_LoginPopup1_Login1_Password={1}&__LASTFOCUS={2}&__EVENTTARGET={3}&__EVENTARGUMENT={4}&__VIEWSTATE={5}&__EVENTVALIDATION={6}&ctl00_LoginPopup1_Login1_LoginButton={7}&ctl00_LoginPopup1_hiddenImagePath={8}&ctl00_cphContent_hiddenVideoDialogTitle={9}&ctl00_cphContent_hiddenShowDefaultVideo={10}", "fg@xyz.com", "abcede", "", "", "", "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", "/wEWCQL9vYfeCAKVyobIBgKB94O0CwKz7JHYDQLsu7CWDgL31sOaAQLmjZ/bDQLto+ilAwLC4KCXAqOJh1kiYkswzxstW/o4u1wgJbA0/EnFO2L8sDvV8fVl", "Log In", "/HSIControl", "Telelisting Instruction Video", "");
HttpWebRequest getRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(getUrl);
getRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
getRequest.CookieContainer.Add(cookies); //recover cookies First request
getRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
//Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
getRequest.ContentType = "text/html";

getRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2";
getRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
getRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
getRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
getRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
getRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
Stream newStream = getRequest.GetRequestStream(); //open connection
newStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length); // Send the data.
newStream.Close();

HttpWebResponse getResponse = (HttpWebResponse)getRequest.GetResponse();
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(getResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
   string sourceCode = sr.ReadToEnd();
   Debug.WriteLine(sourceCode);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A server error in the `500` range means something gone wrong server side. From the looks of your request, I think it might be related to the Viewstate variable you are posting. The server will try to reconstruct the page according to your submitted state. It's not something you just copy and paste. Have you tried only sending the parameters that relate to the login itself (name, password, the name of the button clicked)?

Comment: yes offcourse i have  send the parameters that relate to the login itself but its returning me login page again

Answer (score 0):

For your work see fiddler run the same request and see the cookies match and other post parameters.

And also try :

```
postparameter=  UrlEncode(postparameter)
```

Before converting them to byte and see if that works.

Maybe it works that way.

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you go to the exact page you want to scrape in your browser and then export the full COOKIE set for manual attachment to your script's header?